# The joint pdf of sample maximum and sample mean for uniform distribution?

Tags: distributions, joint-distribution, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

Assume $$\{X_i\}\stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim} \mathcal{Uniform}(0,1)$$ Find the joint p.d.f. of 
$$X_{(n)} \hat= \max \{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_5\}\quad\text{ and }\quad \bar X\hat=\sum^n_{i=1}{X_i}$$

The **motivation** of this question: If a line of length 1 is randomly divided into five parts, computing the probability of there exist one part with length more than 1/4, i.e. find $\Pr\{X_{(n)}\ge \frac{5\bar X}{4} \}$ with the setting above.

Comment: It is hard to see how $X_{(n)}\ge 5\bar{X}/4$ describes the event that there is one part with length more than $1/4.$  For instance, $X_{(n)}$ could be nearly zero and the other four values could all exceed $1/2,$ leaving an initial gap of $1/2.$

Comment: @whuber It's a typo, thank you.

Comment: Please edit your post to display the expression you really want to evaluate, then!

Comment: @whuber this question wants to find the joint p.d.f of $X_{(n)}$ and $\bar X$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X_1, \dotsc,X_n$ is iid  from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.  The maximum is 
$X_{(n)}$ which has a distribution with density $f(u)=n u^{n-1}$.  Represent the joint density of the mean and the maximum as $f(m, u)=f(m \mid u) f(u)$ where $f(m \mid u)$ represents the conditional density of the mean given the maximum.

The order statistics $X_{(1)},\dotsc, X_{(n-1)}$, conditional on the maximum behaves as order statistics from an iid sample of size $n-1$ from the uniform distribution on $[0,u]$, so we can use that and the representation of the mean as
$$
  \bar{X}_n = \frac{u}{n}+ \frac{n-1}{n}\bar{X}_{n-1}
$$
when the maximum $u$ is given. Then the distribution of $\bar{X}_{n-1}$ is a scaled version of the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution),  see also [Can we make the Irwin-Hall distribution more general?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74039/can-we-make-the-irwin-hall-distribution-more-general).  I will leave it at that, you should be able to complete.