# Uniform PDF of the difference of two r.v

Tags: random-variable, density-function, iid

Is it possible to have the PDF of the difference of two iid r.v.'s look like a rectangle (instead of, say, the triangle we get if the r.v.'s are taken from the uniform distribution)?

i.e. is it possible for the PDF $f$ of $j-k$ (for two iid r.v.'s taken from some distribution) to have $f(x) = 0.5$ for all $-1 < x < 1$?

There are no restrictions on the distribution we take $j$ and $k$ from except that the min is -1 and the max is 1.

After some experimentation, I'm thinking this might be impossible.

Comment: The difference of two uniform distributions is a triangular distribution, so if you ask if it is possible to get uniform of a difference of i.i.d. uniforms, then the answer is not.

Comment: Same Q asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048939/difference-between-two-iid-random-variables-is-not-uniformly-distributed   so far without answers!

Comment: It would indeed seem difficult to avoid realizations outside $[-1,1]$ when both $j$ and $k$ have probability mass close to these endpoints.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thank you for sharing that! so it looks like it's impossible.

maybe there's something close?

Comment: @Tim, the iid r.v.'s do not have to be uniform

Comment: It is not possible. To my recollection this is (in slightly different form) already answered somewhere on site. I'll see if I can locate it

Comment: @Glen_b You might be recalling https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125360/uniform-random-variable-as-sum-of-two-random-variables/125450#125450.  It's not *quite* a duplicate, though, because a difference $X-Y$ of iid variables, although expressible as a sum $X+(-Y),$ could involve a sum of variables with non-identical distributions.  I believe a trivial modification of my solution will address this difference; Silverfish's solution looks like it applies directly with almost no modification, but first one has to remove a lot of extraneous material to see that.

Comment: The one I was thinking of involved a sum, yes, but unless my thinking was astray it would still be adaptable to an answer. I thought the thing I remembered was either by chl or cardinal, but it's possible they actually answered in comments.(hence I wouldn't find it by the search). I'll look through your link though. Edit: that wasn't the one I had in mind, but it's a very nice answer -- and it should serve quite well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Theorem:** There is no distribution $\text{Dist}$ for which $A-B \sim \text{U}(-1,1)$ when $A, B \sim \text{IID Dist}$.

---

**Proof:** Consider two random variables $A, B \sim \text{IID Dist}$ with common characteristic function $\varphi$.  Denoting their difference by $D=A-B$.  The characteristic function of the difference is:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\varphi_D(t) = \mathbb{E}(\exp(i t D)) 
&= \mathbb{E}(\exp(i t (A-B))) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(\exp(i t A)) \mathbb{E}(\exp(-i t B)) \\[6pt]
&= \varphi(t) \varphi(-t) \\[6pt]
&= \varphi(t) \overline{\varphi(t)} \\[6pt]
&= |\varphi(t)|^2. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

(The fourth line of this working follows from the fact that the [characteristic function is Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Properties).)  Now, taking $D \sim \text{U}(-1,1)$ gives a specific form for $\varphi_D$, which is:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\varphi_D(t) = \mathbb{E}(\exp(itD)) 
&= \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} \exp(itr) f_D(r) dr \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2} \int \limits_{-1}^1 \exp(itr) dr \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2} \Bigg[ \frac{\exp(itr)}{it} \Bigg]_{r=-1}^{r=1} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\exp(it)-\exp(-it)}{it} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{(\cos(t) + i \sin(t)) - (\cos(-t) + i \sin(-t))}{it} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{(\cos(t) + i \sin(t)) - (\cos(t) - i \sin(t))}{it} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{2i \sin(t)}{it} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\sin(t)}{t} = \text{sinc}(t), \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

where the latter is the (unnormalised) [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).  Hence, to meet the requirements for $\text{Dist}$, we require a characteristic function $\varphi$ with squared-norm given by:

$$|\varphi(t)|^2 = \varphi_D(t) = \text{sinc}(t).$$

The left-hand-side of this equation is a squared norm and is therefore non-negative, whereas the right-hand-side is a function that is negative in various places.  Hence, there is no solution to this equation, and so there is no characteristic function satisfying the requirements for the distribution.  (Hat-tip to [Fabian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7266/fabian) for pointing this out in a related [question on Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824577/inverse-fourier-transform-of-textsinct1-k).)  Hence, there is no distribution with the requirements of the theorem.  $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 4):

This is an electrical engineer's take on the matter, with a viewpoint that is more suitable for dsp.SE rather than stats.SE, but no matter.

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are *continuous* random variables with common pdf $f(x)$.  Then, if $Z$ denotes $X-Y$, we have that 
$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)f(x+z) \ \mathrm dx.$$
The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality tells us that $f_Z(z)$ has a maximum at $z=0$.  In fact, since $f_Z$ is actually the "autocorrelation" function of $f$ regarded as a "signal", it must have a *unique* maximum at $z=0$ and thus $Z$ *cannot* be uniformly distributed as is desired.  Alternatively, if $f_Z$ were indeed a uniform density (remember that it is also an autocorrelation function), then the "power spectral density" of $f_Z$ (regarded as a signal) would be a sinc function, and thus not a nonnegative function as all power spectral densities must be. Ergo, the assumption that $f_Z$ is a uniform density leads to a contradiction and so the assumption must be false.

The claim that $f_Z \sim \mathcal U[-1,1]$ is obviously invalid when the common distribution of $X$ and $Y$ contains *atoms* since in such a case the distribution of $Z$ will also contain atoms. I suspect that the restriction that $X$ and $Y$ have a *pdf* can be removed and a purely measure-theoretic proof constructed for the general case when $X$ and $Y$ don't necessarily enjoy a pdf (but their difference does).

Comment: Part of that doesn't seem right to me.  The characteristic function of the $\text{U}(-1,1)$ distribution *is* the $\text{sinc}$ function, so clearly that kind of Fourier transform is allowable.  Your logic seems to me to lead to [prove too much](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proving_too_much) - it appears to prove not only that $Z$ cannot be uniform, but that the uniform distribution cannot exist at all.  Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Whether or not the characteristic function of $\mathcal U[-1,1]$ exists is not the the issue; it does exist. The pdf of $Z$ is an _autocorrelation_ function. Well, the _power spectral density_ of _any_  autocorrelation function _must_ be a nonnegative function. So, the _assumption_ that $f_Z \sim \mathcal U[-1,1]$ leads to a power spectral density which is a sinc function (that takes on both positive and negative values). Since this is not a valid power spectral density (remember that $f_Z$ is an autocorrelation function also), the assumption that $f_Z \sim \mathcal U[-1,1]$ must be false.