# If V=X+Y how to prove that there is no independent random variables X,Y make V a uniform distribution

Tags: distributions, random-variable, uniform-distribution

If V=X+Y,how to prove that there is no independent random variables X,Y  (with the same distribution function) make V a uniform distribution function on [0,1]

Comment: This question has been previously answered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125360/uniform-random-variable-as-sum-of-two-random-variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uniform random variable as sum of two random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125360/uniform-random-variable-as-sum-of-two-random-variables)

Comment: Yes, thank you.