# How to compute the PDF of a sum of bernoulli and normal variables analytically?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, random-variable, bernoulli-distribution

Can convolution be applied to get a closed form expression for $Z = X + N$ where $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable and $N$ is a zero mean normal random variable independent of $X$?

Comment: Isn't $Z$ just a mixture of Gaussians?

Comment: I don't know; I am not aware of how to show this.

Comment: Not much to show.  I added an answer.

Comment: see [Finite mixture distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures)

Comment: if it is an homework assignment, you need to tell us why you can derive the pdf of $Z$ by the convolution formula. I added the [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag, please read the wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Compute the CDF of $X+N$ using convolution, then differentiate the result.**

The CDF of $X$ is

$$F_X(x) = (1-p)\theta(x) + p\theta(x-1)$$

where $\theta$ is the Heaviside theta function (the indicator function of the nonnegative reals),

$$\theta(x) = 1\text{ if }x \ge 0,\ 0\text{ otherwise}.$$

By definition, the CDF of $X+N$ is

$$F_{X+N}(y) = \Pr(X+N \le y) = \Pr(X \le y-N) =\mathbb{E}(F_X(y-N)).$$

The last equality computes $F_X(y-N)$ for each possible $N=n$ and integrates over them all, weighting them by their probabilities $f_N(n)dn$.  It is a convolution, written as

$$\mathbb{E}(F_X(y-N)) = \int_\mathbb{R} F_X(y-n) f_N(n)dn = (F_X\star f_N)(y).$$

Using the expression of $F_X$ in terms of Heaviside functions, linearity of integration breaks this integral into two convolutions of multiples of $\theta$ against $f_N$.  But computing such convolutions is trivial, because for any distribution function $f$ with integral $F$,

$$(\theta \star f)(y) = \int_\mathbb{R} \theta(y-x)f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^y 1 f(x)dx + \int_{y}^\infty 0 f(x)dx = F(y).$$

It should be apparent that the CDF of $X+N$ is a linear combination of the CDF of $N$ and the CDF of $N-1$.  Thus differentiation of the CDF to obtain the PDF will obtain the same linear combination of the PDFs.  At this point you could simply write down the answer.

Comment: THank you for your answer. I am very weak in this area which is the basics of probability theory & so have few Questions. Can you please clarify? (1) How $Pr$ gets replaced by $E$. (2) Did not understand how $\theta(y-x)f(x) dx$ comes and then it becomes 1(range of integral is $y$ to $\infty$ and 0. (3) Is the final answer GMM? But how is that conclusion arrived from the last step of integration $F(y)$ (4) Plz suggest books where I can learn how to derive myself and the backgrnd info required for it.

Comment: Can you kindly explain how the pdf of $Z$ will be the differentiation of the cdf of $X+N = F(y)$ (from convolution) and what is $y$?

Answer (score 3):

$X$ is Bernoulli distributed with probability $p$.  $N$ has mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$.  So, with probability $1-p$, $Z=X+N$ has mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$ and with probability $p$ it has unit mean and variance $\sigma^2$.  That looks like a mixture of Gaussians to me.

Comment: So, the variance will be same? I could not show with convolution how to compute. It is a homework assignment where I need to show analytically. Can you help me with that? THank you.

Comment: @RiaGeorge If you need the variance then (add it in your question and) you can get it with the help of conditioning by applying the formula $V(N)=E(V(N|X))+V(E(N|X))$.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: Since, $N$ is zero mean, then I think $E[N|X] = 0$. So, we are left with $V(n) = E[V(N|X)] = \sigma^2$. Am I correct? Thank you for pointing this formula; totally forgot.

Comment: In what cases, do we we have GMM with different variance?

Comment: @RiaGeorge Sorry, I meant $Z$ and not $N$, in case if you are interested in the variance of $Z$. I don't understand your latest question ("GMM with different variance ?", could you detail ?)

Comment: Neil G, doesn't the "with probability $p$" part depend on the sample sizes of $X$ and $N$ being the same? It's not clear to me from the original question that this must be the case, so wouldn't there need to be a weighting term in there?

Comment: @RiaGeorge: You can calculate the variance as the second moment minus the mean squared.

Comment: @Alexis: I took $X$ and $N$ to be random variables.  They don't have sample sizes.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: The solution to the pdf is then a mixture of Gaussians which you have concluded straightforwardly and Whuber has shown the reasoning behind your approach. Am I correct in saying that both the answers are the same i.e, the pdf of $Z$ is GMM? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @RiaGeorge Yet I don't know what is "GMM" :)

Comment: SOrry, GMM = Gaussian Mixture Model; you mentioned in your answer that the result of the operation will yield the pdf of $Z$ as a mixture of Gaussians. So, your answer & whuber's are the same?

Comment: @RiaGeorge This is not my answer. But indeed, the two answers are the same.