# Random Variable Transformation

Tags: random-variable, density-function

Consider a Probability density function f(x) which is uniformly distributed between say (-5,5).Now if i define a random variable "y" which is related to the random variable "x" as follows:

y = 1 ; -2.5 < x < 2.5. (zero outside)

Since this mapping neither one to one nor does it correspond to a monotonic function.

How can i find the probability density function of transformed random variable?

Comment: Our site offers a wealth of worked examples and techniques for solving such problems.  Why not [search it](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=distribution%20CDF%20PDF%20cumulative)? One of the higher-voted threads that turns up looks like it fully answers your question: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144138. Please note that your example is not appropriate for your question, because $Y$ will not have a PDF at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above type of random variable transformation requires the use of dirac delta distribution as explained in [RV transformation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities)

The general form is:

[image]

Here f(x)= 1 for -2.5 < x < 2.5 and f(x)=0 outside.

Thus,

fy(y) = 0.5 delta(y-1) + 0.5 delta(y).