# Sampling from Irwin-Hall (Uniform Sum) distribution using rejection sampling

Tags: self-study, sampling, computational-statistics, rejection-sampling

Irwin-Hall Distribution is a probability distribution for a random variable defined as the sum of a number of independent random variables,each having a uniform distribution

> True or False: The greater k is (k being the k in
>   $X=\sum_{n=1}^{k}U_n$) The smaller the c you can find so that c must
>   satisfy $f(x) \leq c g(x)$ for all values of x. ($f$ being the density
>   function of the Irwin-Hall distribution and g being the density function of the proposal distribution).

I have a feeling its false because the more uniform random variables we sum, the bigger the variance is and then the bigger the c would need to be to bound f(x) but not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I suspect you might find the [information in the thread on this distribution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41467) to be useful.  I have no idea what you're actually asking, though, because you haven't told us what $g$ is!

Comment: Thank you for the edit.  Since I suspect the answer depends on what $g$ specifically is, do you have a particular proposal distribution in mind?

Comment: I suspect it could be the normal distribution because the density plots look similar , but the normal distribution's support is infinite whereas the support for the Irwin-Hall distribution is finite so I'm not sure what to do with that..

Comment: Consider any $x$ not in the support: what constraint does that impose on $c$?

Comment: Not sure I follow here but, if there's an x not in the support of f and in the support of g so that would just impose that c>0

Comment: Could you (or anyone) please explain more or give another hint?