# Sum of uniformly distributed random variables over different intervals?

Tags: random-variable, uniform-distribution, convolution

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N$ be $N$ random variables uniformly distributed over the intervals $[a_i, b_i]$ respectively. How does the sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$$

distribute?

This is a generalization of the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), which applies when all the intervals $[a_i,b_i]$ are equal.

Comment: See e.g. "On the distribution of the sum of independent uniform random variables" by S. M. Sadooghi-Alvandi · A. R. Nematollahi · R. Habibi, Statistical Papers 2009

Comment: You could use just about any the many techniques I describe at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43075/919.  It will be messy, but at the very least you could first assume all the $a_i$ are zero by subtracting their sum from $\sum X_i$, thereby reducing the problem to one where the support of each $X_i$ is $[0, b_i-a_i]$.