# Are the family of stable distributions differentiable everywhere on the real line?

Tags: random-variable, heavy-tailed, stable-distribution

Are stable distributions smooth enough for each index of stability $\alpha$ between 0 and 2, and skewness parameter $\beta$ between 0 and 1?

Where there any papers that mention this?

Comment: The methods described in my answer to
 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41467/consider-the-sum-of-n-uniform-distributions-on-0-1-or-z-n-why-does-the/43075#43075 should help you see what happens and why.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is this can be observed from the inverse transformation of its characteristic function. Zolotarev was able to compute the probability density function as follow.

(see Lévy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions-Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics- p.88)

for $\alpha >1$%
$$
p\left( x\right) =\frac{1}{\pi }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left( -1\right) ^{n-1}%
\frac{\Gamma \left( n/\alpha +1\right) }{n!}(\sin \pi n\left( 1+\beta
\right) /2)x^{n-1}
$$
for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ similarly there are for $\alpha <1$ and $\alpha =1$.
Therefore, the pdf of a stable law is a sum series which are all polinomial.
Hence, it is differntiable everywhere.

Comment: This doesn't answer this particular question.

Comment: How come you may see it by applying inverse of Fourier transform in the characteristic function

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? You can also turn it into a comment.

Comment: It is not true that power series necessarily sum to everywhere-differentiable functions.  It is invalid to differentiate them term-by-term unless they are absolutely convergent in a neighborhood of zero.  (It's not hard to show that $p$ is absolutely convergent for $\alpha \gt 1$.)

Comment: Okay @whuber can you show this using this series?

Comment: Hint: you can bound the absolute values of the coefficients with an obvious constant.