# How to find distribution function of sum of 2 random variables that are uniformly distributed?

Tags: random-variable, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I am stuck with this tutorial question in one of my stats module and I would greatly appreciate some help:

Let $X1$ and $X2$ be independent random variables with $a = 0$ and $b = 1$ i.e. $X1$ and $X2$ are uniformly distributed over 0 to 1.

How do you find the distribution function of $Y = X1 + X2$ for $1<y<2$ i.e. what is $F(y)$?

Comment: Convolution approaches with examples [here](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf) and [at Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357672/density-of-sum-of-two-uniform-random-variables-0-1)

Comment: In an answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43075/919 I describe four different ways to find the distribution of $Y.$

Comment: Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent? Uncorrelated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### PDF

We can first derive the PDF using convolution of two PDFs:

**Case 1:** If $0 \leq y \leq 1$, then $f_{X_1}(y - x_2) = 1$ if $ 0\leq x_2 \leq y$, and $f_{X_1}(y-x_2) = 0$ if $x_2 > y$. This means that
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^1 f_{X_1}(y-x_2) dx_2 = \int_0^y 1 dx_2 = y
\end{equation}

---

**Case 2:** If $1 < y < 2$, then $f_{X_1}(y-x_2) = 1$ if $y-1\leq x_2 \leq 1$, and $f_{X_1}(y-x_2) = 0$ otherwise. So
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^1 f_{X_1}(y-x_2) d x_2 = \int_{y-1}^1 1 dx_2 = 2-y
\end{equation}

---

**Conclusion:** $f_Y(y) = y$ if $0 \leq y \leq 1$ and $2-y$ if $1 \leq y \leq 2$. Otherwise, it is zero.

---

### CDF

This means the CDF, which is defined as follows
\begin{equation}
 F_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^y f_Y(y) dy
\end{equation}

**Case 1:** If $y < 0$: Clearly $F_Y(y) = 0$

**Case 2:** If $0 <y < 1$, then 
\begin{equation}
 F_Y(y) = \int_{0}^y f_Y(t) dt = \int_0^y t dt = \frac{y^2}{2}
\end{equation}

**Case 3:** If $1<y<2$, then
\begin{equation}
 F_Y(y) = \int_{0}^y f_Y(t) dt = \int_0^1 t dt + \int_1^y 2-t dt =\frac{1}{2}  -\dfrac{y^2-4y+3}{2}
\end{equation}

**Case 4:** If $y > 2$, then $F_Y(y) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

We need this probability: $F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(X_1+X_2 \leq y)$
Consider a unit square in $[0,1]\ \text{x} \ [0,1]$. The Joint PDF .is distributed uniformly on this square, with value $1$. We draw $x_1+x_2=y$ line and integrate the Joint PDF below the line, which is equivalent to finding *the area of the square below the line*.

There are two cases: $0<y<1$ and $2>y>1$. I guess you need only $y>1$ part, which is "For you to find :)" I believe. You just need to draw the square, draw the line, find the area of the square above the line and subtract from $1$.

Note: There is also a solution with convolution if you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you for the guide! I could find 0 < y < 1 which is 0.5(y^2), but I seem to get stuck moving to 1 < y < 2. Do you mind sharing the integrals for the area of the square above the line and i try to figure out the reasoning myself? @gunes

Comment: Writing the integral is harder here, since the joint PDF is uniform, it is much easier to find the area of the triangle above the line and then subtract it . But, the integral of $P(Y\geq  y)$  is $$\int_{y-1}^{1}{\int_{x_1}^{1}{1 \ dx_2dx_1}}$$.