# probability density of a random vector greater than some value?

Tags: probability, distributions, probability-inequalities, random-vector

In single dimension, the probability that a random variable $X$ is greater than some value $x$ is easily related to the cumulative distribution(c.d.f.) as $Pr(X > x) = 1 - F(x)$ if only $Pr[X \leq x] = F(x)$ is known.

If instead we have a random vector $[X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n]$, could you please let me know if there is a direct relation between the c.d.f and the probability $Pr[X_1 > x_1, X_2 > x_2, \cdots, X_n > x_n]$ if I only know $F(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) = Pr[X_1 \leq x_1, X_2 \leq x_2, \cdots, X_n \leq x_n]$? I know it is not $1 - F[x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n]$ in this case.

Comment: $\newcommand{P}{\Bbb{P}}$Hint: Let $A_i = \{ X_i> x_i\}$ and $B_i = A_i^c = \{ X_i \le x_i\}$. Note that $$\begin{align}\P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} A_i\right) &= \P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} B_i^c \right) \\ &= \P\left(\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B_i \right)^c\right) \\ &= 1- \P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B_i \right). \end{align}$$

Now, the probability of this union can be obtained using the inclusion-exclusion principle. It will involve probabilities of intersections of the $B_i$, which are obtainable from the joint CDF $F$ by taking limits to $\infty$ of the other variables.

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388713.  Likely many answers can be found in the hits at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=copula+cdf, too.