# Finding the distribution of X-Y if X and Y are iid uniform (-a,a)

Tags: distributions, independence, uniform-distribution

Suppose X and Y are independent and follow uniform distribution (-a,a). How do we find the distribution of X-Y? I tried finding the area with the help of a diagram for cases when x-y>0 and x-y<0. I want to know what is the right way to do it.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: Consider that $-Y$ and $Y$ has the same distributios, and have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41467/consider-the-sum-of-n-uniform-distributions-on-0-1-or-z-n-why-does-the

Comment: Who knows what the "right" way might be -- but many different ways are given (in great detail) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41467.

Answer (score -1):

So the individual means of X and Y are both 0, and so the mean of (X - Y) will also be 0.

The covariance of the two is 0, so we can just add up the variances.
The variance of one variable is $(2a)^2 / 12=a^2/3$, so the variance of (X - Y) will be $2a^2 / 3$.